# Make a python script available to other person

Tags: python, exe

I have a python script that, in short, take some information from a xls file in the same directory and, based on that information, send some e-mail and update the xls file.
For my purpose sometimes I also have to manually update the xls file.
I would like to make this script available for a friend.
The best thing would be that he can manually update the file and then execute the script, better if he doesn't have to install python. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pyinstaller to make exe from your python script. [guide](https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script/)